# Why does this armature jump between solutions?

Tags: armature

[image]
[image]
I have attached the blend file. The armature jumps when the IK target crosses the X-axis. Maybe there's an easy fix?

Here's a link to the blend file. Not sure why it's so large.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TJF270htDNWtlT6UQml1yufR0AkuD1w2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I assume you mean things like the jumps  in Bone.001's rotation at frame 48 and around frame 103?  Those appear to be the IK solver jumping between two solutions where there's a discontinuity. The usual solution is to add a pole target, but I'm not sure where I'd put one in an IK chain that long.

Comment: Ok thanks marty. Each link has 3 armature bones, maybe that's not great for the solver?

Comment: I don't know the details of the solver, so I don't know how it takes into account all of the locked transforms, but the main issue with the solver is that each new joint introduces another degree of freedom that allows rotational discontinuity. That shows up as the jumps. Pole targets reduce the freedom by telling the solver which way a joint should point. Your armature seems to have two "joints" that can jump, but the solver can only have one Pole target.

Comment: The other thing that helps is to slightly bend the model at the joints in edit mode and bend the armature to fit.  This helps the solver figure out which way to favor if there are two different bends at a joint that could result in a solution.

Comment: Thanks marty. I cleaned up the armature by removing redundant bones. Perhaps the dissolved armature will provide more clarity as to why the arm finds alternate solutions in an instant.